# Mediawiki Image URL fetch

Tags: mediawiki-api

I am wondering if there is an API to fetch the image URL for a page on Wikipedia in BULK.

The API that I looked at is 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&redirects=&prop=extracts|pageimages|revisions&pithumbsize=200&exlimit=1&exintro=&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&titles=Abraham_Lincoln|China|Japan

but I get image URL only for the first title.

Answer (score 1):

[The default value for `pilimit` is 1.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageimages) If you want to get more pageimages in a single query, set it to a larger value, like `max`:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&redirects=&prop=extracts|pageimages|revisions&pithumbsize=200&exlimit=1&exintro=&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&titles=Abraham_Lincoln|China|Japan&pilimit=max